# Laravel 5.4 render parent view before child view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

Is it possible to force laravel to execute the parent view then the child view ? I use a master view with some view composers to create a menu and set some variables, then in my sitemap subview, because the master view is computed after I end up having my menu not created yet.

```
@extends('layout.master')


@section('content')
    {{-- Render this after layout.master --}}
@endsection
```

Maybe I missed some possibility here.

Comment: Have you tried using `@parent` and making sure the content is included in the master template?

Comment: `@parent` is just to chose where to content will be append but the child view is still (sadly) render first.

Comment: Can you show the code from your master view the relates to the variable from your composer and also where you're yielding the child view?

Answer (score 0):

If you watch code that blade generate in storage/framework/views/some_name.php you can see next code:

```
<?php echo $__env->yieldContent('content'); ?>
```

It`s working something like PHP inlcude, when code come to this line it come in to this file with content.

That`s why you can not load master view and then subview.